# Map navigation property to main table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have class `Contract` with two properties `TotalAmount` and `InstallmentAmount`

```
public class Contract
{
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    public Amount TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public Amount InstallmentAmount { get; set; }
    //other Amounts
}

public class Amount
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to configure Entity Framework so it can create one table `Contract` with structure like below:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| ContractId | TotalAmountValue | TotalAmountCurrency | ... 
|     999    |       1000       |         USD         | ...
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You could use owned types, but first you should wonder whether you really want  such a design. For one, it's not normalized, which is going to haunt you forever. In particular, (because of denormalization) there's a dependency between each amount and its currency which is a loose relation when everything is in one table: only the field names reveal the relationship. In a separate Amount table each amount is unambiguously tied to a currency. I would go for this Amount table where amount will have a type (Total, Installment, ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your concrete question. What you are asking is possible by mapping the `Amount` class as [owned entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities).

The simplest way to do that is to use `[Owned]` attribute:

```
[Owned] // <--
public class Amount
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

or fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Owned<Amount>();
```

This by default will create a single table in question, but the column names will be `TotalAmount_Value`, `TotalAmount_Currency` etc. If that's ok, you are done.

If you want to remove the underscore in column names, you'd need to use `OwnsOne` fluent API for each `Contract.Amount` property and then `Property(...).HasColumnName(...)` for each `Amount` property. Instead of doing that manually, you could do that in a loop using the EF Core metadata services. For instance:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>(builder =>
{
    var amounts = builder.Metadata.GetNavigations()
        .Where(n => n.ClrType == typeof(Amount));
    foreach (var amount in amounts)
    {
        var amountBuilder = builder.OwnsOne(amount.ClrType, amount.Name);
        var amountProperties = amountBuilder.OwnedEntityType.GetProperties()
            .Where(p => !p.IsKey());
        foreach (var property in amountProperties)
            amountBuilder.Property(property.Name).HasColumnName(amount.Name + property.Name);
    }
});
```

Comment: I especially like the naming part. Just one question, is `.Where(p => !p.IsKey()` necessary or is it just a general precaution?

Comment: @Gert Yeah, it's needed in order to skip the automatic shadow PK/FK of the owned  entity. W/o that criteria I'm getting error.                            .

Comment: @IvanStoev Is it good approach or better try as @Gert Arnold suggests create `Amount` table? I deserialize XML to objects based on XSD schema that why I have such design.

Comment: Ah, good to know that. I like it when people test their code... ;)

Comment: @user3373603 About the approach... it all depends on what you're gonna use these amounts for. If it's only some information that will only be displayed and not used in subsequent process/queries you may get away with storing the amounts as a flat record. As soon as you're going to do further processing, f.e. aggregation, or querying specific types of amounts you'll be glad to have them in a separate table. Then you'll have to disect the XML object --well, doable. Also, in a flat design, if ever you're going to have new amount types you need to change the database schema.

Comment: (continued) ... and with a flat table it's more of a hassle to make currencies refer to a currencies table, which would be a natural thing to do in any database design.

Comment: @IvanStoev you don't need to do so much complexity to rename the column. You can simply do as follows:  `modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>().OwnsOne(
    o => o.Amount,
    am =>
    {
       am.Property(p => p.Value).HasColumnName("TotalAmountValue");
       am.Property(p => p.Currency).HasColumnName("TotalAmountCurrency");
    });`

Comment: @Tanvir I know you can do that for *single* property. But read the OP again. They have `TotalAmount`, `InstallmentAmount` plus "*other Amounts*". You don't want to repeat that code for all amounts.

Comment: @IvanStoev so what? other `other Amounts` will also be written in same fashion with a separate configuration class! 

Comment: Hehe, love it. I tried your code tonight and found one slight improvement, which is the generic version `builder.OwnsOne<T>(name)`. It returns a typed `ReferenceOwnershipBuilder` that allows further typed configurations. For example references off of an owned type that, when using SQL Server, must be set non-cascading when there are multiple owned-type properties.

Comment: @Gert That's good for sure. But only if one needs to configure other concrete aspects of a concrete owned type, e.g. `builder.OwnsOne<Amount>(amount.Name).Property(e => e.Value)…`. Non generic version though is perfect for simple *naming convention* like this - in fact one can loop over all entity types, their owned type navigations (`.Where(n => n.ForeignKey.IsOwnership)`) and apply a code similar to the above.