# EntityFrameworkCore - When specifying multiple properties

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm using VS 2019 with EF 6, and below are the models I've used for the development. When I try to map a foreign key "CountryId" to "Estore" model in the EF configuration I'm facing the below issues.

```
PM> EntityFrameworkCore\Enable-Migrations
```

Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework6\Enable-Migrations' for Entity Framework 6.
Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations.

```
PM> EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration Estore_Table
```

The properties expression 'es => Convert(es.Address.CountryId, Object)' is not valid. The expression should represent a simple property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'. (Parameter 'propertyAccessExpression')

Please advise.

```
    //Country Model:-
    public class Country
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Estore> Estores { get; set; }
    }

    //Address Model:-
    public class Address
    {
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string Pincode { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
    }

    //Estore Model:-
    public class Estore
    {
        public int EstoreId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
    }

    //Estore fields EF configuration
    public class EstoreConfiguration
    {
        public EstoreConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<Estore> entityBuilder)
        {
            //DB Table 
            entityBuilder.ToTable("Estores", Constants.Database.DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

            //Table Primary Key
            entityBuilder.HasKey(es => es.EstoreId);

            //Foriegn Key       
            entityBuilder.HasOne(es => es.Country).WithMany(es => es.Estores).HasForeignKey(es => es.Address.CountryId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
            //StateId & CityId mapping pending

            //Table Fields
            entityBuilder.Property(es => es.EstoreId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().IsRequired();
            entityBuilder.Property(es => es.Name).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            entityBuilder.Property(es => es.Code).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired();

            //Address
            entityBuilder.OwnsOne(es => es.Address, adr => { adr.Property(es => es.AddressLine1).HasColumnName("AddressLine1").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(); });
            entityBuilder.OwnsOne(es => es.Address, adr => { adr.Property(es => es.AddressLine2).HasColumnName("AddressLine2").HasMaxLength(50); });
            entityBuilder.OwnsOne(es => es.Address, adr => { adr.Property(es => es.AddressLine3).HasColumnName("AddressLine3").HasMaxLength(50); });
            entityBuilder.OwnsOne(es => es.Address, adr => { adr.Property(es => es.Pincode).HasColumnName("Pincode").IsRequired(); });
            entityBuilder.OwnsOne(es => es.Address, adr => { adr.Property(es => es.CityId).HasColumnName("CityId").IsRequired(); });
            entityBuilder.OwnsOne(es => es.Address, adr => { adr.Property(es => es.StateId).HasColumnName("StateId").IsRequired(); });
            entityBuilder.OwnsOne(es => es.Address, adr => { adr.Property(es => es.CountryId).HasColumnName("CountryId").IsRequired(); });
        }
    }

    //Context 
    public class EcommerceContext : DbContext
    {
        public EcommerceContext()
        {

        }

        public EcommerceContext(DbContextOptions<EcommerceContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Estore> Estores { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            new EstoreConfiguration(modelBuilder.Entity<Estore>());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The exception tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn’t resolve that.  Please can you help me on that issue.

Comment: I’m facing issue in the below line                 entityBuilder.HasOne(es => es.Country).WithMany(es => es.Estores).HasForeignKey(es => es.Address.CountryId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `entityBuilder.OwnsOne(es => es.Address)` is `OwnedNavigationBuilder<Estore,Address>`. You have to use this builder to define navigation properties on the owned type.

```
var addressBuilder = entityBuilder.OwnsOne(es => es.Address);
addressBuilder.OwnsOne(p => p.Address)
            .HasOne(a => a.Country).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.CountryID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

Of course you can also use this `addressBuidlder` to set the column names, or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57094491/861716).

Note that `HasOne(a => a.Country).WithMany(c => c.Estores)` isn't possible. This is because `Address` isn't an entity in its own right. The foreign key `CountryId` is part of the `Estore` entity and EF can't build `Address` entities from that table.

If you want `Country` to have a collection of addresses *and* the same addresses as reference in `Estore` that you have to make `Address` an entity of its own.